# How to format text and embed a video with Quill?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, reactjs, quill

I started to integrate a WYSIWYG into a blog project, I'm using Quill for this (I had no experience with it before). I was able to customize my editor the way it was required, what I don't understand is how to deal  with text format and embed videos. I have two fields in my post form, "preview" and "content" (two quill editors) while introducing the text I can give format to it (header, italic, underline...etc) and when click the embed video option the editor allows me to add the link and visualize the embed video in that moment. When I press my save button it stores the post in my db but in my single post page I visualize all the fields without format (header, italic, underline...etc) and also no embed video. How can I give format and show the video? Any help would be appreciated.

I read the Quill documentation and tried to understand how to deal with this using deltas but I don't know how to make this work.

I'm using Meteor + React, this is my code (I'll show only relevant code):

This is my lib, quill.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import QuillLib from './vendor/quill.js';
import { ud } from '/helpers/lib/main.jsx';

class Quill extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.id = ud.shortUID();
}

componentDidMount() {
  const that = this;
  const toolbarOptions = [
    [{ font: [] }],
    [{ header: 1 }, { header: 2 }],
    [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
    [{ align: [] }],
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
    ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
    [{ script: 'sub' }, { script: 'super' }],
    [{ indent: '-1' }, { indent: '+1' }],
    [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
    ['video'],
    ['image'],
];

const quill = new QuillLib(`#quill-editor-container-${this.id}`, {
  modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions,
  },
  theme: 'snow',
});
const content = this.props.content;
  quill.setContents(content);
  quill.on('text-change', (delta) => {
    if (that.props.onChange) {
      that.props.onChange(quill);
    }
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="wysiwyg-wrapper">
      <div id={`quill-editor-container-${this.id}`}></div>
    </div>
  );
 }
}
export default Quill;
```

This is my input form component, list.jxs

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { PostSchema } from '/modules/blog/lib/collections.jsx';
import Quill from '/modules/quill/client/main.jsx';

export class BlogCategory extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      post: {
        content: '',
        preview: '',
      },
    };
    this.onPreviewChange = this.onPreviewChange.bind(this);
    this.onContentChange = this.onContentChange.bind(this);
  }

  onPreviewChange(content) {
    this.state.post.preview = content.getText();
    this.setState(this.state);
  }
  onContentChange(content) {
    this.state.post.content = content.getText();
    this.setState(this.state);
  }

  save() {
    const content = this.state.post.content;
    const preview = this.state.post.preview;
    const post = new PostSchema();
    post.set({
      content,
      preview,
    });
    if (post.validate(false)) {
      const id = post.save(); 
    }
    console.log(post.getValidationErrors(false));
  }

  renderCreatePostForm() {
   let content;
   if (this.state.showForm) {
     content = (
      <form action="">
        <Quill 
           content={this.state.post.preview} 
           onChange={this.onPreviewChange}
        />
        <Quill
           content={this.state.post.content}
           onChange={this.onContentChange}
        />
      </form>
     );
    }
    return content;
  }
  render() {
    let content = (
      <div className="col-xs-12">
        {this.renderActions()}
      </div>
    );
   if (!this.props.ready) {
    content = <p>LOADING...</p>;
   }
   return content;
  }
}
export default createContainer(() => {
  const handleValidPost = Meteor.subscribe('posts');
  return {
    ready: handleValidPost.ready(),
    posts: PostSchema.find({}).fetch(),
  };
}, BlogCategory);
```

And finally my collections.jsx

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
export const PostCollection = new Mongo.Collection('Posts');
export const PostSchema = Astro.Class({
  name: 'PostSchema',
  collection: PostCollection,
  fields: {
    content: {
     validator : Validators.and([
       Validators.required(),
       Validators.string(),
       Validators.minLength(3)
     ])
    },
    preview: {
     validator : Validators.and([
       Validators.required(),
       Validators.string(),
       Validators.minLength(3)
     ])
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you post a working code example to highlight your problem please?

Comment: If the code was working, he wouldn't be asking

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I guess you could use React Player to display video's or audio links but I wouldn't know how to implement it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While getting `Quill` contents by `getText`, you lost your text format and video information. Using `getText`, all non-string data will be omitted. `Quill` data are defined as [Delta](https://quilljs.com/docs/delta/) (which is a JSON object).

You can fix this by updating your `onPreviewChange` and `onContentChange` to use `getContents` instead of `getText`. Save these `Delta` to DB and load it again.

```js
  onPreviewChange(content) {
    this.state.post.preview = content.getContents();
    this.setState(this.state);
  }
  onContentChange(content) {
    this.state.post.content = content.getContents();
    this.setState(this.state);
  }
```